# how to send data from php to android not using json

Tags: php, android

i using httpPost method  to send data from android to php.

Now i am want to send data from php to android ?

i need the simple and flexible method like: httpPost, but there from php to android

not from android to php

how it ?

Comment: phpmyadmin is a browser-based script for accessing data in a MySQL database, it is not the database itself, that is MySQL

Comment: i mean using php file not phpmyadmin itself

Comment: Start by writing a php script.... there's one or two tutorials available on the interweb if you search (even one or two examples in the PHP docs)

Comment: why avoid json? you want to create your own format?

Comment: no but the json is hard for me
if you have the easy way in json no wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP can just print whatever you want.  It can be as simple as

```
<?php
    print("This is my return value");
```

JSON is a common format, but it can be anything.  Below is an complete java example of reading the PHP script's value.

```
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = null;
    httppost = new HttpPost("www.myURL.com");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
}

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
    String line = "0";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: yes i mean as this answer.
thnx

but here when i am will not send data (just receive) 
the nameValuePairs  can set to null ?
as this:  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(null, "UTF-8"));

?

Comment: I've never tried that, but give it a shot.  Otherwise, you can just send an empty list new UrlEncodedFormEntity(new ArrayList<NameValuePair>())

Comment: ya it connect but it cause this error !

04-13 11:43:05.669: E/log_tag2(1248): Error converting result java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: Without seeing your code I can only guess, but it sounds like an unrelated error.  Something you're doing with handlers or threads.

Comment: i but the code in AsyncTask in doInBackground  function

Comment: That should be fine.  There must be something else you're doing, like trying to update the UI thread from doInBackground.

Comment: No, there is right but i called used Toast to print the result.
there is error, i use Log.i
thank you.